# Buying a 7 day Subway Pass Online for Charlie Card

Tags: boston

I could find ways to buy a monthly pass or load stored value, but could not find a way to buy a 7 day pass (even though it is advertised [here](https://www.mbta.com/fares). Any ideas how to buy a 7 day pass?

Comment: I can't prove it offhand but I expect you can only buy 7 day passes in a station.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That's what I ended up doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buy 7-day CharlieTickets and CharlieCards in person at MBTA subway stations. I personally recommend the 7-day Zone 1A LinkPass. It's printed on a paper CharlieTicket, but it will additionally allow you to use the commuter rail within [Zone 1A](https://www.mbta.com/cr-map-zones) and the [Charlestown Ferry](https://mbta.com/schedules/Boat-F4/line) for the same price as the CharlieCard.

Comment: Thanks! And do you know of anyway to buy It online?

Comment: No, I believe you'll need to just buy it on the machines in the subway station when you arrive. It should be quite easy to do, though. If you need assistance, there are MBTA staff members at many stations and Customer Assistance areas at the major stations like South Station and Back Bay.